# Nested Recycler view height doesn't wrap its content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I have an application that manage collections of books (like playlists).

I want to display a list of collection with a vertical RecyclerView and inside each row, a list of book in an horizontal RecyclerView.

When i set the layout_height of the inner horizontal RecyclerView to 300dp, it is displayed correctly but **when i set it to wrap_content, it doesn't display anything.**
I need to use wrap_content because I want to be able to change the layout manager programmatically to switch between vertical and horizontal display.

[image]

Do you know what i'm doing wrong ?

My Fragment layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white">

    <com.twibit.ui.view.CustomSwipeToRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shelf_collection_listview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.twibit.ui.view.CustomSwipeToRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Collection element layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFF">

        <!-- Simple Header -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/empty_collection"
            android:id="@+id/empty_collection_tv"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/collection_book_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> <!-- android:layout_height="300dp" -->

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Book list item :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="180dp"
              android:layout_height="220dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shelf_item_cover"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:maxHeight="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cover"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my Collection Adapter :

```
private class CollectionsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CollectionsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final String TAG = CollectionsListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;

    // Create the ViewHolder class to keep references to your views
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView mHeaderTitleTextView;
        private final TextView mHeaderCountTextView;

        private final RecyclerView mHorizontalListView;
        private final TextView mEmptyTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            mHeaderTitleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.collection_header_tv);
            mHeaderCountTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.collection_header_count_tv);

            mHorizontalListView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.collection_book_listview);
            mEmptyTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_collection_tv);
        }
    }


    public CollectionsListAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CollectionsListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(" + parent.getId() + ", " + i + ")");
        // Create a new view by inflating the row item xml.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shelf_collection, parent, false);

        // Set the view to the ViewHolder
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);

        holder.mHorizontalListView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        holder.mHorizontalListView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        holder.mHorizontalListView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CollectionsListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(" + holder.getPosition() + ", " + i + ")");

        Collection collection = mCollectionList.get(i);
        Log.d(TAG, "Collection : " + collection.getLabel());

        holder.mHeaderTitleTextView.setText(collection.getLabel());
        holder.mHeaderCountTextView.setText("" + collection.getBooks().size());

        // Create an adapter if none exists
        if (!mBookListAdapterMap.containsKey(collection.getCollectionId())) {
            mBookListAdapterMap.put(collection.getCollectionId(), new BookListAdapter(getActivity(), collection));
        }

        holder.mHorizontalListView.setAdapter(mBookListAdapterMap.get(collection.getCollectionId()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCollectionList.size();
    }
}
```

And finally, the Book adapter :

```
private class BookListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookListAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final String TAG = BookListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    // Create the ViewHolder class to keep references to your views
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mCoverImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mCoverImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.shelf_item_cover);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        BookListAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (BookListAdapter.ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        int position = holder.getPosition();
        final Book book = mCollection.getBooks().get(position);

        // Click on cover image
        if (v.getId() == holder.mCoverImageView.getId()) {
            downloadOrOpenBook(book);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void downloadOrOpenBook(final Book book) {
        // do stuff
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private Collection mCollection;

    public BookListAdapter(Context context, Collection collection) {
        Log.d(TAG, "BookListAdapter(" + context + ", " + collection + ")");
        mCollection = collection;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder(" + parent.getId() + ", " + i + ")");
        // Create a new view by inflating the row item xml.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shelf_grid_item, parent, false);

        // Set the view to the ViewHolder
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        holder.mCoverImageView.setOnClickListener(BookListAdapter.this); // Download or Open

        holder.mCoverImageView.setTag(holder);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder(" + holder.getPosition() + ", " + i + ")");

        Book book = mCollection.getBooks().get(i);

        ImageView imageView = holder.mCoverImageView;
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(book.getCoverUrl(), imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCollection.getBooks().size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use wrap_content to change the layoutmanager between vertical and horizontal?

Comment: If i set the layout_height to a specific value (lets say the height of an element for the horizontal layout manager), it only display the first line of the list with the vertical layout manager.

Comment: But recyclerView has a scrollView built in, so you can just scroll through items...or am I missing the point here? Sorry trying to understand

Comment: I want to scroll through collection items but not the inner book list (except horizontally). Something like ExpandableListView.

Comment: i facing same question with you, have you resolved now?

Comment: As a workaround, i'm setting the height of the inner view programmatically but that is not satisfying.

Comment: Is this Bug still existing with new API 22.1.1 ?

Comment: @Twibit  how u resolved the issue i have to achieve same functionality using wrap_content height with horizontal scrollview

Comment: Hey of all the solutions I'm confused is this MyLinearLayoutManager  supposed to be used only for parent, only for child or for both?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/35623177/2826147 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35623132/2826147 answer

Comment: I used LruCache instead of mBookListAdapterMap - I think it's more efficient then a HashMap.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update**

Many issues relating to this feature in version 23.2.0 have been fixed in 23.2.1, update to that instead.

With the release of Support Library version 23.2, `RecyclerView` now supports that!

Update `build.gradle` to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

or any version beyond that.

> This release brings an exciting new feature to the LayoutManager API: auto-measurement! This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

This can be disabled via `setAutoMeasurementEnabled()` if need be. Check in detail [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

Comment: Be careful! Here are new bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619022/nullpointerexception-in-dissapearence-animation-of-recyclerview-from-support-v-2

Comment: does that address the bug above?

Comment: This is not working properly always seen the blank space in between each item

Comment: Please careful the height of parent layout which contains the child recycler view must be wrap content.

Comment: Wow... thanks a lot for this information. I have been waiting for this feature for quite some time now.

Comment: Version `23.2.1` of RecyclerView seems to have fixed several bugs. Works very well for us. If not, you can even try with `24.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: It works for me! The blank space between each item was because the height of item layout must be set to wrap_content also

Comment: 24.0 have some issues https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210085#makechanges , use 23.2.1 instead

Comment: In Version 23.2.1 of RecyclerView, wrap_content works for layout_height ! yay

Comment: for more details you may check this https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/37007605#comment88

Answer (score 124):

@user2302510 solution works not as good as you may expected. Full workaround for both orientations and dynamically data changes is:

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fairly well but does not seem to take ItemDecoration (such as separators) into account.

Comment: Not sure why yet, but scrolling doesn't seem to work. I tried this code with a vertically scrolling layout... When the items are less than the height of the screen everything works fine. When there are more items than can be displayed on the screen though, srolling doesn't work.

Comment: I think If there are more items than screen size - you do not need to modify original LayoutManager.

Comment: @Twibit I tested it right now and seems to work with ItemDecoration s.

Comment: @DenisNek There is a way to make it work when there are more items than fit in the screen?

Comment: This doesn't work with content change animations - the size of the recyclerview snaps rather than smoothly grows/shrinks.

Comment: This works for setting the height to wrap content but after that , recycle view scrolling is not `smooth` as it was. Any help on that?

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - 'onBindViewHolder' is being called TONS of times (about 100 times) for a recycler view with 2 views

Comment: use `measureChildWithMargins(view,widthSpec,heightSpec)` then you don't have to take margin into consideration yourself. BTW. I'm having problem getting `MessuredHeight` of the child no matter what `MeasureSpec` I pass. You have any idea on this ? I mean if I set the height of the child to wrap_content.

Comment: Here is a refined version of the class which seems to work and lacks problems other solutions have: https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java

Comment: I've got this to work, but same as @MKJParekh said, it's not that smooth anymore. If anyone could fix that, then this would be perfect! If interested, this is what I had before using this class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675006/recycle-listview-calculate-height

Comment: @se.solovyev I just want to comment that this works perfectly. Everybody check out his link!

Comment: Thanks @se.solovyev. Your code worked and I was looking for a way to do this for a long time.

Comment: How can we achieve the same for `gridlayoutmanager` and `staggeredgridlayoutmanager` considering span count in mind?

Comment: what to write to orientation and reverseLayout ?

Comment: I am using this recyclerview inside scrollview and make recylerview wrap content using this code. But scrolling scrollview is not smooth. Solution is http://stackoverflow.com/a/32283439/3736955

Comment: @se.solovyev  how to use your code ? instead of using LinarLayoutManager may i  need to use your class defined in link  ? https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java

Comment: @Pin  how u used https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java

Comment: Just use it instead of the default LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: @Pin  but how will it work for Horizontal recyclerview because i m uable to pass orientation to the class ?

Comment: It has a setOrientation function. Are you sure you're looking at the correct file?

Comment: @Pin  can u pls come online here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidiansthe-great-indian-android-developer-ever

Comment: @se.solovyev your library worked perfectly for what I was looking for. Thanks for the help! Everyone, check out his project on [GitHub](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/solovyev/android/views/llm/LinearLayoutManager.java)!

Comment: What if I wanted to apply this to a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Comment: @DenisNek what should be the value for reverseLayout?

Comment: worked well with vertical view not working with horizontal...any suggestion?

Comment: @se.solovyev thanks! by the way, with this layout manager the last item decoration is not draw. Possible bug?

Comment: @Jjang maybe, please report it on a project's page on github

Comment: @se.solovyev : is there similar solution for gridLayoutManager also . Facing problem with GridLayoutManager .

Answer (score 39):

The code up above doesn't work well when you need to make your items "wrap_content", because it measures both items height and width with MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED. After some troubles I've modified that solution so now items can expand. The only difference is that it provides parents height or width MeasureSpec depends on layout orientation.

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {


        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {

            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    heightSpec,
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    widthSpec,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    recycler.bindViewToPosition(view, position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution has worked best for me. Denis' didn't seem to measure enough and the view was still scrollable. Sinan's only appeared to behave properly when there was a single child. Note: my child views used `wrap_content`

Comment: To enable scrolling when it hits the view parent's bounds I had to put in `switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            if (height < heightSize) break;
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }`

Comment: Excellent solution. This worked perfectly. On a side note, rather than using a constructor, I just made a private instance variable and a setter/ getter method with a Constant final int ORIENTATION (Just in case someone else is having a problem) and then used that to check the passed orientation.

Comment: I've bumped with issue on Lollipop and above, ScrollView which wraps RecyclerView works incorrectly (there is no flings) when you tried scrolling above RecyclerView. For resolving this issue you need make NotScrollableRecyclerView (custom) and override onInterceptTouchEvent, onTouchEvent methods with not calling super implementations of them and you should return false in both methods.

Comment: This works but i don't understand why it is so unnecessarily complex to just have the thing measure its height after its children's height is calculated...

Comment: @Kaerdan thankyou much, your solution works for me :)

Comment: Should this be applied to Parent RecyclerView or only to Child or to both?

Comment: It should be applied to those RecyclerViews that you want to have wrap_content.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 22):

Existing layout manager do not yet support wrap content.

You can create a new LayoutManager that extends the existing one and overrides onMeasure method to measure for wrap content.

Comment: That is not what i expected but it seems to be true. See: [RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java#L6018) & [LinearLayoutManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java)

Comment: @yiğit , Will recyclerView support wrap content by default?

Comment: It depends on LayoutManager not RecyclerView.

It is in our roadmap.

Comment: @yigit Doesn't this render `setHasFixedSize(boolean)` useless with the default layout managers? Anyway, great to know it's on the roadmap. Hope it comes out soon.

Comment: Yep, because LM cannot have fixed size if its size depends on adapter contents. The main difference is whether RV processes updates before onMeasure or before onLayout. Also, with resize, it is quite hard to do predictive animations since LM should need to know final size to measure itself properly whereas pre-layout will happen after measure (it is like rolling time back).

Answer (score 22):

As @yiğit mentioned, you need to override onMeasure(). Both @user2302510 and @DenisNek have good answers but if you want to support ItemDecoration you can use this custom layout manager.

And other answers cannot scroll when there are more items than can be displayed on the screen though. This one is using default implemantation of onMeasure() when there are more items than screen size.

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }

    // If child view is more than screen size, there is no need to make it wrap content. We can use original onMeasure() so we can scroll view.
    if (height < heightSize && width < widthSize) {

        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {

   View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

   // For adding Item Decor Insets to view
   super.measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getDecoratedLeft(view) + getDecoratedRight(view), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingBottom() + getDecoratedBottom(view) , p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

            // Get decorated measurements
            measuredDimension[0] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to use it with GridLayoutManager just extends it from GridLayoutManager and change

```
for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i = i + getSpanCount())
```

Comment: This is the solution that works correctly, I've tested all others in this thread and they all had issues

Comment: This solution worked very well for me too. The only issue was that it doesn't properly account for wrapped text in the child. See my answer above for the solution to that problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for gridlayout (yes, I applied the changes). First it seems to work, then I change orientation back and forth, and the height is changed compared to the original height. Also the view's doesn't behave as expected (eg. onclicks don't work on most of them while with a simple gridlayoutmanager they work).

Comment: How can we achieve the same for `gridlayoutmanager` and `staggeredgridlayoutmanager` considering span count in mind?

Comment: is this MyLinearLayoutManager supposed to be applied to the child recycler view or to the parent? or both?

Comment: In certain circumstances your code doesn't work for me.
I must add `heightSize == 0 || widthSize == 0 ||` to `if (height < heightSize && width < widthSize)`

Comment: @Sinan kozak How do you get "getSpanCount()" if i want to use it in gridlayout ?

Answer (score 21):

### UPDATE March 2016

By [Android Support Library 23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) of a support library version. So all **WRAP_CONTENT** should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

This allows a RecyclerView to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as **using WRAP_CONTENT for a dimension of the RecyclerView, are now possible**.

you’ll be required to call **setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)**

***Fixed bugs related to various measure-spec methods in update***

Check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 14):

This answer is based on the solution given by Denis Nek. It solves the problem of not taking decorations like dividers into account.

```
public class WrappingRecyclerViewLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public WrappingRecyclerViewLayoutManager(Context context)    {
    super(context, VERTICAL, false);
}

public WrappingRecyclerViewLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);
        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }
    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            width = widthSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            height = heightSize;
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec, int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec, getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
        int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec, getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
        view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        Rect outRect = new Rect();
        calculateItemDecorationsForChild(view, outRect);
        measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
        measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin + outRect.bottom + outRect.top;
        recycler.recycleView(view);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Finally, the only thing that works correctly. Great work. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid item position 0(0). Item count:0 exception.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to extend LayoutManager can be just set the size of the view manually.

Number of items per row height (if  all the items have the same height and the separator is included on the row)

```java
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mListView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = mAdapter.getItemCount() * getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.row_height);
mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Is still a workaround, but for basic cases it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, only working solution. Poor Android :(

Answer (score 6):

Here I have found a solution: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772

It is in no way my solution. I have just copied it from there, but I hope it will help someone as much as it helped me when implementing horizontal RecyclerView and wrap_content height (should work also for vertical one and wrap_content width)

The solution is to extend the LayoutManager and override its onMeasure method as @yigit suggested.

Here is the code in case the link dies:

```
public static class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

        measureScrapChild(recycler, 0,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

        int width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
        int height = mMeasuredDimension[1];

        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                width = widthSize;
                break;
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                height = heightSize;
                break;
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bingo! worked perfect with horizontal but not with vertical

Answer (score 5):

Used solution from @sinan-kozak, except fixed a few bugs. Specifically, we shouldn't use `View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED` for *both* the width and height when calling `measureScrapChild` as that won't properly account for wrapped text in the child. Instead, we will pass through the width and height modes from the parent which will allow things to work for both horizontal and vertical layouts.

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {    
        if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, heightMode),
                mMeasuredDimension);

            width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
            }
        } else {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize, widthMode),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);

            height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
            }
        }
    }

    // If child view is more than screen size, there is no need to make it wrap content. We can use original onMeasure() so we can scroll view.
    if (height < heightSize && width < widthSize) {

        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {

   View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

   // For adding Item Decor Insets to view
   super.measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
    if (view != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getDecoratedLeft(view) + getDecoratedRight(view), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + getDecoratedTop(view) + getDecoratedBottom(view) , p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

            // Get decorated measurements
            measuredDimension[0] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I've tested and it works, but only if the `RecyclerView` is nested in a `LinearLayout`. Doesnt work with `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the workaround shown in all answer is correct , that is we need to customize the linear layout manager to calculate the height of its child items dynamically at run time. But all answers not working as expected .Please the below answer for custom layout manger with all orientation support.

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

private static boolean canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
private static Field insetsDirtyField = null;

private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];
private final RecyclerView view;

private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
private boolean hasChildSize;
private int overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS;
private final Rect tmpRect = new Rect();

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) {
    super(view.getContext());
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(view.getContext(), orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

public void setOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode) {
    if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
    if (this.view == null) throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");
    this.overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
    ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, overScrollMode);
}

public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
    return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    final boolean hasWidthSize = widthMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
    final boolean hasHeightSize = heightMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

    final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

    final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

    if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
        // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        return;
    }

    final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

    initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter entities. This
    // happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method. As a workaround let's clear the
    // recycler now (it should not cause any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never
    // called whiles scrolling)
    recycler.clear();

    final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
    final int adapterItemCount = getItemCount();
    // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data before the animation is
    // done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the
    // state
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
        if (vertical) {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            }
            if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            }
            if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (exactWidth) {
        width = widthSize;
    } else {
        width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        if (hasWidthSize) {
            width = Math.min(width, widthSize);
        }
    }

    if (exactHeight) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else {
        height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        if (hasHeightSize) {
            height = Math.min(height, heightSize);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (view != null && overScrollMode == ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS) {
        final boolean fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

        ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, fit ? ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER : ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
    }
}

private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
    if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
        // already initialized, skipping
        return;
    }
    if (vertical) {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
    } else {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
    }
}

@Override
public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    // might be called before the constructor of this class is called
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    if (childDimensions != null) {
        if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
        }
    }
    super.setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void clearChildSize() {
    hasChildSize = false;
    setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
}

public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
    hasChildSize = true;
    if (this.childSize != childSize) {
        this.childSize = childSize;
        requestLayout();
    }
}

private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize, int[] dimensions) {
    final View child;
    try {
        child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "MyLinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

    final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

    // we must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    // this method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods
    calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, tmpRect);

    final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
    final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

    final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());
    final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

    child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

    dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

    // as view is recycled let's not keep old measured values
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    recycler.recycleView(child);
}

private static void makeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p) {
    if (!canMakeInsetsDirty) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (insetsDirtyField == null) {
            insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
            insetsDirtyField.setAccessible(true);
        }
        insetsDirtyField.set(p, true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    }
}

private static void onMakeInsertDirtyFailed() {
    canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("MyLinearLayoutManager", "Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Android Support Library now handles WRAP_CONTENT property as well. Just import this in your gradle.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

And done!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the work of Denis Nek,
it works well if the sum  of item's widths is smaller than the size of the container. other than that, it will make the recyclerview non scrollable and only will show subset of the data.

to solve this problem, i modified the solution alittle so that it choose the min of the provided size and calculated size. see below:

```
package com.linkdev.gafi.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.linkdev.gafi.R;

public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.c = context;
    }


    private Context c;
    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];


    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);



        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }


        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        int widthDesired = Math.min(widthSize,width);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthDesired, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all solutions, they are very useful
but this only works fine for me

```
public class  LinearLayoutManager extends android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

    public LinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {


            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {

                measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        heightSpec,
                        mMeasuredDimension);

                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                        widthSpec,
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        mMeasuredDimension);
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }

        if (height < heightSize || width < widthSize) {

            switch (widthMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    width = widthSize;
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            switch (heightMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    height = heightSize;
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        recycler.bindViewToPosition(view, position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply wrap the content using RecyclerView with the Grid Layout**

Image:
[Recycler as GridView layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvmpk.png)

Just use the GridLayoutManager like this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mRecyclerGrid=new GridLayoutManager(this,3,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerGrid);
```

You can set how many items should appear on a row (replace the 3).