# Recycler View Not Showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-navigation

I have been making an app that uses a recycler view in a navigation drawer. Why the contents of the recycler view are not showing up. The view is definitely there as I can see the scroll shadows. I am not sure what I have done wrong, as the app does not crash when it is run.

Navigation Drawer Fragment:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testPref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private View containerView;
    private Boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private Boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private DrawerAdapter adapter;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        mFromSavedInstanceState = false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        adapter = new DrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return layout;
    }

    public static List<DrawerRow> getData(){
        List<DrawerRow> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
        String titles[] = {"Link 1","Link 2","Link 3","Link 4"};
        for (int i = 0 ; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++){
            DrawerRow current = new DrawerRow();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }

        return data;
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawerOpen, R.string.drawerClosed){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState){
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveToPreferences(Context context, String prefName, String prefValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString(prefName, prefValue);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String prefName, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(prefName,defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    List<DrawerRow> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    public DrawerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<DrawerRow> data) {
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row , viewGroup,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        DrawerRow current = data.get(i);
        viewHolder.title.setText(current.title);
        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
        }
    }
}
```

Drawer Row:

```
public class DrawerRow {
    int iconId;
    String title;
}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <!--Main Content -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Nav Drawer -->
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="uk.co.clickcomputing.hhscweatherstation.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Drawer Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:padding="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:id="@+id/list_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:padding="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/list_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Navigation Drawer Fragment Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eee"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_drawer_img_desciption"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/nav_drawer" />
    
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/drawerList">
    
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the layout file that includes the RecyclerView?
My guess is that you've set width or height to wrap content, which is not yet supported by the default layout managers.

Comment: @yigit updated with the layout

Comment: so as I guessed, you have android:layout_height="wrap_content" on the recycler view which is not yet supported by the default layout managers.

You can either change it to match_parent or override onMeasure in your layout manager and do the measurement yourself.

Comment: @yigit still nothing is displayed

Comment: that doesn't make sense. Do you have a sample app that you can attach? APK should be enough to debug but if you can attach w/ sources, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning the item count as 0 which tells that there is no rows to show. You should return the size of the List as shown below.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
```

Comment: I had this issue when I update my dataList `dataList=getMyItems()`. instead I use `dataList.addAll(getMyItems());`

Answer (score 36):

Replace following line

```
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

with

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));    
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hey @mangal can you explain the reasoning for the above logic.

Comment: it's the same....? no difference...

Answer (score 9):

I agree that you need to return the correct item number but I think you might have a problem with setting the recycler view's height to wrap_content as well. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content) link very helpful. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Adding `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` to the `RelativeLayout` solved my problem.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    ...
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: no luck on this. it's crashing...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure RecyclerView parent container width not set as WrapContent

Comment: As simple as this, excellent answer. I changed to match_parent the recycler and now it appears

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

and layout height in your row is `android:layout_height="match_parent"` but must be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1):

The common problem is that you might have forgotten to set your recyclerview with adapter

example in kotlin

```
adapter= CartAdapter(this)
    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    binding.productCartRecycler.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    binding.productCartRecycler.adapter = adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for your RecyclerView's width and height attributes, if they are set to wrap content, change it to match parent or constraint your view in some specific area.
Also check for Parent view's width attribute, if it's set to wrap content change it to match parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have given static height and match_parent. It works for my Example I haved added it in nested recyclerview.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                     android:id="@+id/new_store_page_phoneNumber_rv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:scrollIndicators="bottom"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        app:adapter="@{adapter}"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching data from the network, make sure you are reloading/refreshing your adapter in the UI thread. This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you use **data.size()** and **wrap_content** to the **height** of the parent layout of the Recycler View.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35043241)