# android: RecyclerView inside a ScrollView (or parallax)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a fragment with **2 cardviews** with multiple controls within.

**below** the second cardview I have a **recyclerview**, this works **perfect**.

the problem is that the recyclerview starts **very bottom of the screen**, and scroll the recylcerview is very **small**.

**previously used a listview, and this kept me fit your content and thus make scroll across the screen at once, but with recylclerview can not.**

How to make when I scroll in the recyclerview, **controls go up** like parallax effect?

EDIT: more clear, imagine 2 cardviews in a fragment, these occupy 80% of the screen, above of these, a recyclerview with a list of 100 items, but the scroll is so tiny...the listview let me adapt to the "content" and scroll the entire screen at once.

this is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/svScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/cvCampos1"
            layout="@layout/ctlcabeceralibreta" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/cvCampos2"
            layout="@layout/ctlcabeceralibreta2" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvRegistros"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cvCampos2"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

this is the screenshoot:

[image]

Comment: please be a little clearer because it is not clear what the actual problem is

Comment: imagine 2 cardviews in a fragment, these occupy 80% of the screen, below of these a recyclerview with a list of 100 items, but the scroll is so tiny...the listview let me adapt to the "content" and scroll the entire screen at once.

Comment: set a min height to the recylerview ?

Comment: or put a scrollview around all set recyclerView height to wrap content. and diable scrolling of the recyclerview with: .setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });

Comment: I tried what you said, but the scroll only works for both cardview and does nothing when I want to scroll the recyclerview

Comment: putting a fixed height works !!! but I need to calculate the height of the number of items in the list...

Comment: Dont' use a scrollable view inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview/26573338#26573338

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue? I am stuck at a similar point.  I am able to scroll from the recyclerview, but cant scroll the entire screen with fields before the recyclerview

Comment: yes, the solution for now I have used and works on all devices that have tried, is to put the property on the recyclerview android: layout_height = "wrap_content" (inside a ScrollView) and then use this LinearLayoutManager for recyclerview http://stackoverflow.com/a/27616854/518657, which calculates the height of the items, the only problem is that all items must be of the same height. if anyone has a more elegant solution to this problem, please post it, it can not be that there is NO solution to this very basic problem.

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058496/set-starting-height-of-collapsingtoolbarlayout/33194147#33194147. in this sample you can replace recyclerview with nestedscrollview

Comment: Please check the following answer [which uses custom layout manager to calculate the height](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33542789/3257178)

Comment: You have to give 0dp height to recyclerView and give height at runtime according to total no. of item * height of each item in dp.       Like if we have 10 textview of 40dp each, then vertical recyclerView height will be 10*40 dp = 400dp and 10dp for horizontal. Then it will works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above case what you need to do is to use multiple `ViewHolders` in the same `recyclerview`.

I see that you have three type of layouts there. The first two cards and other layouts in your `recyclerview`.

[RecyclerView with multiple View Types](http://deepakbaliga.com/index.php/2015/07/17/recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types/) gives you an example how to use multiple viewtypes in a simple recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

> putting a fixed height works !!! but I need to calculate the height of
>   the number of items in the list

this works for listviews (i dont tested it with recyclerview)

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

**Src:**

[Full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/1847899)

Comment: yes, this was the function i used in my app when i used the listview, but now i used a recyclerview, and not found the equivalent of this function.

Comment: can u add your layout xml and a screenshot to your question .. pls

Comment: You should say that this answer [was not written by you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19311197/2823516)