# Set starting height of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to be able to scroll on the ImageView inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout. So how that would be possible, and How to set a starting height of that Image view?

My ImageView height is 280p, at the start of the activity I want to show 200p and then I can scroll down to see the rest of the Image. I have seen something similar in WhatsApp application.

Here is a link to see what I want :

[image]

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.Profile">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"         
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/tof" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/content_profile" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content profile code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.Profile">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: did you try to call `scrollTo(0, 200);` on your `NestedScrollView` ?

Comment: Hi Buddy Did that issue solved for you. I have same requirement like yours.Please let me know if it solved

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) implement your Request

this is a layout in cheesesquare

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Related"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Cheesesquare sample application does not implement what the OP requested. It does implement a normal CTL.

Comment: Doesn't work! But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33153297/2835520) do what is expected.

Answer (score 22):

Actually AppBarLayout has special method to apply such offset:

```
final int setAppBarTopBottomOffset(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int newOffset, int minOffset, int maxOffset)
```

Unfortunately it has package-private access level, but we can invoke it through such intermediate chain:

```
private void setAppBarOffset(int offsetPx){
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    behavior.onNestedPreScroll(mCoordinatorLayour, mAppBarLayout, null, 0, offsetPx, new int[]{0, 0});
}
```

One thing to be mentioned - this method should be called after mAppBarLayout is already prepared and measured. So the right way is to call it via view's post method.

```
mCoordinatorLayour = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_coordinator);
mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);

mAppBarLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int heightPx = findViewById(R.id.iv_header).getHeight();
        setAppBarOffset(heightPx/2);
    }
});
```

Comment: a question please: shouldnt be a negative offsetPx to reduce the AppBarLayout's height?

Comment: Work for me,but there is not animations when OffSet changed.

Comment: For those who are having trouble to get it working, use the new non deprecated method `behavior.onNestedPreScroll(mCoordinatorLayour, mAppBarLayout, null, 0, offsetPy, new int[]{0, 0}, 0);`.

Comment: @OliverAdam, This code didnt worked for me. I have a bitmap with 1000 px and want to show only 100px image when page load. Have you checked this code with this scenario?

Answer (score -2):

Just add:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

to the ImageView in the CollapsingToolbarLayout.
You can find more [here](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/).

Comment: Here is a link to extend the answer: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html - scroll to near the bottom or search for "parallax" on the page.