# CollapsableToolbarLayout with custom Toolbar height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm creating a layout using a `CoordinatorLayout` holding an `AppBarLayout` with a `CollapsableToolbarLayout` and a `Toolbar`. Below the app bar is a `RecyclerView`.

When scrolling in the `RecyclerView`, the `Toolbar` should collapse, similar to the CheeseSquare demo app. The difference from that demo is that 1) I want my `Toolbar` (including the title) always statically at the top (so I've set `app:titleEnabled` on my `CTL`), and 2) I don't want to collapse the app bar fully into *only* showing the single line `Toolbar` since I have some text views etc below the `Toolbar` which the app bar should never collapse beyond. I am using a custom `Behavior` to control these text views during collapsing, and all this works fine.

Problem is, I don't seem to grasp how to best set the anchor point at which the collapsing will end. I know that the app bar will collapse until it snaps to to the height of the `Toolbar`. So I would need to either put my custom views inside the toolbar, hence increasing the height of the `Toolbar` itself, or somehow instruct the `CTL` to anchor to my custom view instead. However, whenever I change the height of the `Toolbar`, the title text gets strangely aligned and I haven't found a good way of keeping it properly aligned with any set of reasonable attributes.

Question is, should I be playing with the height of the `Toolbar` at all, or is there a way of getting the `CTL` to stop collapsing at some other anchor point than the bottom of the `Toolbar`?

Or should I indeed modify the height of the `Toolbar` and place my own layout in it that includes the title text, and manually make sure to align it vertically with the toolbar icons etc? The best I've managed so far is to place a `LinearLayout` containing a `TextView` inside the `Toolbar`, with a hard-coded `layout_marginTop="14dp"`, which might have compat issues. It seems really strange that it wouldn't be possible to increase the height of a `Toolbar` while still maintaining the default title text position.

Or should I not use the `CTL` at all but instead create my completely custom behavior also for the parts that collapses the app bar during initial `RecyclerView` scroll events?

I've searched for similar questions obviously, and the closest I've found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058496/set-starting-height-of-collapsingtoolbarlayout) which does not address my problem with the title text getting messed up.

My current layout, including the ugly hard-coded manual title `TextView` inside the `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"/ >

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_behavior="my behavior class">

        <!-- My custom views to be shown in the app bar, animated through custom behavior -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```