# How to set initial expand limit for collapsing Toolbar layout like in whatsapp?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to expand the collapsing toolbar for certain height at initial stage like in Whats app, contact application.how its possible?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFSlP.jpg)

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot for layout?

Comment: added image please check it @SachinSaxena

Comment: Yo, maybe this link would help, it already has the answer which is the layout there and the question is I think the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058496/set-starting-height-of-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: set the initial height of your AppBarLayout

Comment: is there any attribute available for that in xml? @DeepanshuHarbola