# How to hide an ImageView when scrolling down a TextView contents?

Tags: java, android

how can i create a layout like this picture. When scrolls down texts, it hides imageview. What kind of layout should I use for this?

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxliS.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyssO.png)

Comment: Try with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058496/set-starting-height-of-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to implement collapsing toolbar using support design library.

add below code into your app level gradle file

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

now add this code into your **xml** file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

please remember you need to use `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` in your `ImageView`.

Hope this will help you.