# Two Column RecyclerView inside scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I want my 2 columns `RecyclerView`, i.e. using `GridLayoutManager`, inside scrollview. I found a way to put single column recyclerview inside scrollview from this [link](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager), but i cant figure out how to put Grid `RecyclerView` inside scrollview.

Comment: Please, avoid putting a scrollable View inside another one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264951/problems-with-gridview-inside-scrollview-in-android

Comment: i have to...because as per client requirement my home activity is quite big and for small mobile screen users i have to provide scroll bar so they can see whole things

Comment: no @AmarbirSingh i am not using gridview, here i am using RecyclerView and i also dont want to use third party library

Comment: A RecyclerView already has its own scrollbar. You will get troubles managing a double scrolling bar

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i can understand...can you suggest me any other way?

Comment: Get Rid of the ScrollView

Comment: then how can i manage to show all the data?

Comment: Check This--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048603/android-recyclerview-inside-a-scrollview-or-parallax   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515904/android-recyclerview-inside-a-scrollview

Comment: I think the linearlayout manager  you linked here  will work for Gridlayoutmanager too, because GridLayoutmanager is child class of Linearlayoutmanager. Please try it  with GridLayoutmanager.

Comment: You don't need to show ALL of your UI on a single screen. Divide your UI in functional bits.

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal i have tried, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution. Work perfect for me.

**my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_grid_recycler_view"
    tools:context="com.example.recyclerview_horizontal.GridRecyclerView">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gridview inside scrollview"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gridview inside scrollview"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.gridrecyclerviewscroll;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerAdapter.DynamicHeight {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    ArrayList<Integer> size;
    TextView txt;
    long sumHeight=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

       // txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);

        size = new ArrayList<>();
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(R.drawable.index1);
        list.add(R.drawable.index2);
        list.add(R.drawable.index3);
        list.add(R.drawable.index4);
        list.add(R.drawable.index5);
        list.add(R.drawable.index6);
        list.add(R.drawable.index8);
        list.add(R.drawable.index9);
        list.add(R.drawable.index10);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void HeightChange(int position, int height) {
        size.add(height);
        sumHeight = calSum();

        float density = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float viewHeight = sumHeight * density;
        recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) sumHeight;
    }

    private long calSum() {
        long tot=0;
        for(int i=0;i<size.size();i++){
            tot = tot + size.get(i);
        }
        return tot;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
package com.example.gridrecyclerviewscroll;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by nteam on 23/10/15.
 */
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    Context context;
    private DynamicHeight dynamicHeight;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> list, DynamicHeight dynamicHeight){
        this.list = list;
        this.dynamicHeight = dynamicHeight;
    }
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        this.list = list;

    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.img.setImageResource(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
        holder.itemView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int cellwidth = holder.itemView.getWidth();
                int cellheight = holder.itemView.getHeight();

                if(dynamicHeight!=null) dynamicHeight.HeightChange(position, cellheight);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface DynamicHeight {
        void HeightChange(int position, int height);
    }
}
```

All credits goes to `@Ashkan`

Comment: Also you can customize your `LayoutManager` as per your requirement,

Comment: yes but that only work with single recyclerview....i want it with grid type recyclerview

Comment: Oh. Ok. So finally above answer fullfill your requirement? So for others may be helpful.