# Android - LinearLayout childs dispose like StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, staggered-gridview

I have 4 elements (images) in LinearLayout which i want to dispose like the StaggeredGridView.
Can I do this with a LinearLayout ? There is other method ?

[image]

The images are added dynamically

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how exactly do you want to dispose. The elements inside the linear layout or the whole layout?

Comment: Something like the image above i just added

Comment: @Miguerto Go for `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you consider using a `RecyclerView` with an `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`?
An example: [here](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

If you are going to have always maximum of 4 items then you can do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But I do not recommend this. I would go with the `RecyclerView`, nothing wrong with using it only for 4 items.

Comment: Yes, i know it work with RecyclerView, but can i have to create recyclerView for just 4 items ?

Comment: But can I use this RecylerView in other RecylerView ? Because the parent is also a RecyclerView

Comment: Yes you can do that. Check this example where they show Cards inside of a RecyclerView and every Card has a new RecyclerView. So it is basicly a RecyclerView of RecyclerViews. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166624/android-how-can-i-insert-a-recyclerview-inside-cardview

Comment: After many tries, i can display image in RecyclerView but i have a problem beacause the second RecyclerView must have a defined height. For StaggeredGridLayoutManager i have to set height to "wrap_content". There is a trick ?