# How to have a ListView/RecyclerView inside a parent RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add some child Views (List Items), which come to me from JSON formatted data. Each child list is under a parent list item row. How can I populate it in `RecyclerView` for each row item (Parent items with child list items)?

I have tried using `RecyclerView` within `RecyclerView` parent row (for populating child lists), but here child views are not visible.

## Parent Adapter Class

```
public class DigitizedPrescAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DigitizedPrescAdapter.ListItemViewHolder>{
    private List<PrescriptionModal> prescriptionList;

    MedicinesInPrescAdapter adapter;

    public DigitizedPrescAdapter(List<PrescriptionModal> prescriptionListModal) {

        if (prescriptionListModal == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "PrescriptionList must not be null");
        }
        this.prescriptionList = prescriptionListModal;
    }

    @Override
    public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.item_row_digitised_request,
                        viewGroup,
                        false);
        return new ListItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(
            ListItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        PrescriptionModal model = prescriptionList.get(position);

        viewHolder.prescnum.setText("Prescription "+ ++position);
        viewHolder.prescNo.setText("Prescription: "+model.getPrescriptionID());
        viewHolder.doctorType.setText("Type: "+model.getDoctorType());
        viewHolder.doctorName.setText("Doctor: "+model.getDoctorName());
        viewHolder.patientName.setText("Patient: "+model.getPatientName());

        adapter = new MedicinesInPrescAdapter(model.getLstproduct());
        viewHolder.lstMedicines.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prescriptionList.size();
    }

    public final static class ListItemViewHolder
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView prescnum;
        TextView prescNo;
        TextView doctorType;
        TextView patientName;
        TextView doctorName;
        CheckBox selectAll;
        RecyclerView lstMedicines;

        public ListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            prescnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prescnum);
            prescNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prescNo);
            doctorType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctorType);
            patientName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.patientName);
            doctorName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctorName);
            selectAll = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
            lstMedicines = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lstAllMedicines);
            MyLinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new MyLinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
            lstMedicines.setHasFixedSize(false);
            lstMedicines.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }
}
```

## Child Adapter Class

```
public class MedicinesInPrescAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MedicinesInPrescAdapter.MedicineListItemViewHolder>{

    List<Modal_Product_List> prescriptionProducts;

    public MedicinesInPrescAdapter(List<Modal_Product_List> prescriptionListProd) {

        if (prescriptionListProd == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "PrescriptionProductList must not be null");
        }
        this.prescriptionProducts = prescriptionListProd;
    }

    @Override
    public MedicineListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.item_row_medicine_productlist,
                        viewGroup,
                        false);
        return new MedicineListItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(
            MedicineListItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Modal_Product_List modelMedicine = prescriptionProducts.get(position);

        viewHolder.medicineName.setText(modelMedicine.getMedicinename());
        viewHolder.medQty.setText(modelMedicine.getQuantity());
        viewHolder.days.setText("30");
        viewHolder.Amount.setText(modelMedicine.getQuantitybasedprice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return prescriptionProducts.size();
    }

    public final static class MedicineListItemViewHolder
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView medicineName;
        EditText medQty;
        TextView days;
        TextView Amount;
        CheckBox selectMe;

        public MedicineListItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            medicineName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicineName);
            medQty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medQty);
            days = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.days);
            Amount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            selectMe = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selectMe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [Expandablelistview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/), put the parent as the header and child as its view.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I got this issue few days ago and finally solved it. All you have to do is **@override the layout manager onMeasure** function as below:

CustomLinearLayoutManager

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private static final String TAG = CustomLinearLayoutManager.class.getSimpleName();

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {

        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i, View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                mMeasuredDimension);
                

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        try {
            View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(0);//fix IndexOutOfBoundsException

            if (view != null) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

                int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);

                int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);

                view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
                measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
                measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
                recycler.recycleView(view);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

You can just copy and paste this `CustomLinearLayoutManager` set it to your child `RecyclerView` like this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new CustomLinearLayoutManager(mContext);
holder.childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**Remember** : Don't use `CustomLinearLayoutManager` in parent `RecyclerView`, or it will throw error.

Comment: Thanks pptang, its working fine, but the height is still an issue, if i try to scroll, some childs loose their visibility and also i have some edittexts in rows. So i need that their data should not be lost while scrolling..

Comment: But what if the nested RecyclerView has an unpredictable amount of elements?  Then each time this RecyclerView shows up in it's parent RecyclerView's row, it will have a different height.

Comment: I know what your are saying. It still works in that case. Any issue occurred while your were trying?

Comment: @pptang i did as you suggested i lost items below the child recycler view what should i do ?

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh send me your code snippet and I can help fix it. My mailbox: donaldduck518@gmail.com

Comment: 2nd row of child recyclerview is not visible

Comment: i have set as you said but getting this error.
 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: how to link the recyclerview parent with the child?

Answer (score 16):

By **Android Support Library 23.2** of a support library version 23.2.0. So all `WRAP_CONTENT` should work correctly.

Please update version of a library in **gradle** file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

This allows a `RecyclerView` to size itself based on the size of its contents. This means that previously unavailable scenarios, such as using `WRAP_CONTENT` for a dimension of the `RecyclerView`, are now possible. You’ll find all built in LayoutManagers now support auto-measurement.

you’ll be required to call `setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)`

> Below is the sample code

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(context); 
layout.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
```

As `setAutoMeasureEnabled` is deprecated alternate solution 
This method was deprecated in API level 27.1.0. Implementors of `LayoutManager` should define whether or not it uses AutoMeasure by overriding `isAutoMeasureEnabled()`.

Comment: setAutoMeasureEnabled should be called upon what?

Comment: LayoutManager. `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            layout.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);`

Comment: i see automeasureenabled is deprecated. but what should we use then ? i dont see any replacement mentioned

Comment: @j2emanue as per the documentation you have override the LayoutManager and set  isAutoMesure to true

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 27.1.0. Implementors of LayoutManager should define whether or not it uses AutoMeasure by overriding isAutoMeasureEnabled().

Answer (score 14):

If I understand, you want a RecyclerView with RecyclerView rows.
In this case I recommend you to use an **expandable RecyclerView**, using [this lib](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview). Just follow the [expandable example](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview/tree/master/example/src/main/java/com/h6ah4i/android/example/advrecyclerview/demo_e_basic) within the link.

There are many more cool features in the same lib, like Drag and Drop, Swipeable rows... Watch this less than a minute [example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=S7cSwMArjUQ).

You just have to add the lib to the dependencies in your `gradle.build` file, like following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.7.4'
}
```

To be able to `import` the lib in your java files.

Comment: hey Geraldo I'm trying to use this lib and just noticed it says: "If you are using support library v23.0.x, please use v0.8.1 instead." In my dependencies I have `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'`,  `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0' ` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'` do I have to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: you should not create new Adapter each time when calls onBindView(), you should do that once in the onCreateView().

**The Best Way - to use any library, for example -** [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

How to add a NestedRecyclerView:

**Step 1:** Add the `ViewModel` interface to your `Modal_Product_List`

```
public class Modal_Product_List implements ViewModel {

    String getMedicinename() { ... } //your method
    int getQuantity() { ... } //your method
    int getQuantitybasedprice() { ... } //your method
}
```

**Step 2:** Create a `ViewBinder` for the `Modal_Product_List`:

```
private ViewRenderer getModalProductViewRenderer() {
    return new ViewBinder<>(
            R.layout.item_row_medicine_productlist, //your child layout id
            Modal_Product_List.class //your child item class
            (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
                .setText(R.id.medicineName, model.getMedicinename())
                .setText(R.id.medQty, (String) model.getQuantity())
                .setText(R.id.amount, (String) model.getQuantitybasedprice())
                .setChecked(R.id.selectMe, ...)
    );
}
```

**Step 3:** Add the `CompositeViewModel` interface to `PrescriptionModal` or extend from `DefaultCompositeModel`:

```
public class PrescriptionModal extends DefaultCompositeViewModel {

    String getPrescriptionID() {...} //your method
    String getDoctorType() {...} //your method
    String getDoctorName() {...} //your method
    String getPatientName() {...} //your method

    @Override
    List<Modal_Product_List> getItems() { return yourProductItems; }
}
```

**Step 4:** Create a `ViewBinder` for the `PrescriptionModal`:

```
private ViewRenderer getModalProductViewRenderer() {
    return new CompositeViewBinder<>(
        R.layout.item_row_digitised_request, //your parent item layout
        R.id.lstAllMedicines, //your nested RecyclerView
        PrescriptionModal.class, //your parent item class
        (model, finder, payloads) -> finder
            //no need to set child items, it will set automatically
            .setText(R.id.prescnum, "Prescription:" + model.getPrescriptionID)
            .setText(R.id.doctorName, "Doctor:" + model.getDoctorName())
            .setText(R.id.doctorType, "Type:" + model.getDoctorType())
            .setText(R.id.patientName, "Patient:" + model.getPatientName())
    ).registerRenderer(getModalProductViewRenderer()); //register ModalProductViewRenderer
     .registerRenderer(...) //if you need you can create other renderer and register here
);
```

**Step 5(Optional):** If you need a Custom `LayoutManager`, then extend the `CompositeViewBinder` and override the `createLayoutManager` method and use it instead of `CompositeViewBinder`

```
public class CustomCompositeViewBinder extends CompositeViewBinder {

    //...

    @Override
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager createLayoutManager() {
        return new MyLinearLayoutManager(getContext(), VERTICAL, false);
    }
}
```

**Step 6:** Initialize `RendererRecyclerViewAdapter` and register renderer:

```
RendererRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

adapter.registerRenderer(getModalProductViewRenderer());
adapter.registerRenderer(...); //if you need you can create other renderers

adapter.setItems(getPrescriptionListModal());
```

It is really short and simple way to add a Nested RecyclerView