# Android RecyclerView Scroll not working after Layout edit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a horizontal scrolling RecyclerView inside an another RecyclerView which means parent RecyclerView(vertical scroll) and child RecyclerView(Horizontal scroll) inside parent RecyclerView. I referred couple of questions regarding this requirement and found a better solution from this question [How to have a ListView/RecyclerView inside a parent RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011995/how-to-have-a-listview-recyclerview-inside-a-parent-recyclerview-i-have-a-pare/) and implemented successfully.
After the child adapter's layout file edit the child RecyclerView's scrolling disabled.

here are my codes,
this is the parent fragment.

```
public class MarketFragment extends Fragment {

private String log = "abcpappaHomeFragment";
private Button loadMore ;
private ArrayList<ProductCategoryBean> productCategoryList=null;
private ProductCategoryService productCategoryService;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

public MarketFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    productCategoryService = new ProductCategoryService();
    productCategoryList =(ArrayList<ProductCategoryBean>)productCategoryService.getAllCategories();
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.market_fragment, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.market_recycle_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MarketRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),productCategoryList,this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

this is LayoutFile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="bodhiinfo.abcpappa.activity.MarketFragment">>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/market_recycle_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
```

adapter class for parent RecyclerView

```
public class MarketRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ProductCategoryBean> productCategoryList=null;
private List<ProductBean> productDetailList=null;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
public MarketFragment marketFragment;
// private marketList


public  MarketRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<ProductCategoryBean> productCategoryList,MarketFragment marketFragment){
    this.context = context;
    this.productCategoryList =(ArrayList<ProductCategoryBean>)  productCategoryList;
    this.marketFragment = marketFragment;
    }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.market_fragment_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context);
    return viewHolder;
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    ProductCategoryBean productCategoryBean =(ProductCategoryBean)productCategoryList.get(position);

    viewHolder.product_category_name_id.setText(productCategoryBean.getUtxt_product_category());
    ProductService productService = new ProductService();
    productDetailList = (ArrayList<ProductBean>)productService.getProductDetailsByCategoryId(productCategoryBean.getPki_product_category_id()+"");
    viewHolder.product_recycle_list.setHasFixedSize(false);
    viewHolder.mLayoutManager = new ChildCustomLinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    viewHolder.product_recycle_list.setLayoutManager(viewHolder.mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MarketRowRecyclerAdapter(context,productDetailList);
    viewHolder.product_recycle_list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productCategoryList.size();
    }

public static class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView product_category_name_id;
public RecyclerView product_recycle_list;
public ChildCustomLinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public Context context;

public View view;
public ClipData.Item currentItem;
public ViewHolder(final View itemView,final Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;
    product_category_name_id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_category_name_id);
    product_recycle_list =(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_recycle_list);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}
}
}
```

layout of parent RecyclerView adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="bodhiinfo.abcpappa.activity.MarketFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- linear layout for market heading row-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/market_heading_raw"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_category_name_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/market_heading"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View More.."
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/product_recycle_list"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

child RecyclerView adapter

```
 public class MarketRowRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketRowRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ProductBean> productList;
private Context context;

MarketRowRecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<ProductBean> productList){

   this.productList =(ArrayList<ProductBean>)productList;
   this.context = context;

}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.market_product_image_view, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v,context);
    return viewHolder;
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    ProductBean productBean=(ProductBean)productList.get(position);
    ImageCacheManager imageCacheManager= ImageCacheManager.INSTANCE;
    ImageLoader imageLoader=imageCacheManager.getImageLoader();
    viewHolder.market_product_image_id.setImageUrl("http://www.ps4home.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mad-Catz-F.R.E.Q.5-Headset-for-PC-and-Mac-Black.jpg", imageLoader);
    viewHolder.product_text_id.setText(productBean.getTxt_product_name());
    viewHolder.product_actual_price_id.setText("Rs :"+productBean.getTxt_product_actual_price());
    viewHolder.product_actual_price_id.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.product_actual_price_id.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    viewHolder.product_app_price_id.setText("Rs :" + productBean.getTxt_product_price_in_app());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

public static class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView product_text_id;
    public TextView product_actual_price_id;
    public TextView product_app_price_id;
    public NetworkImageView market_product_image_id;
    public Context context;

    public View view;
    public ViewHolder(final View itemView,final Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        product_text_id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_text_id);
        product_actual_price_id= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_actual_price_id);
        product_app_price_id= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_app_price_id);
        market_product_image_id = (NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_product_image_id);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
  }
  }
```

Child Adapter Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
tools:context="bodhiinfo.abcpappa.activity.MarketFragment">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/market_product1_image_frame_id"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/market_product_image_id"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_text_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/product_one"
            android:background="@drawable/textbackgrounds"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_actual_price_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_dark_black"
        android:text="@string/product_one"
        android:layout_below="@+id/market_product1_image_frame_id"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_app_price_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/product_one"
        android:textColor="@color/text_dark_black"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_actual_price_id"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

ChildCustomLinearLayoutManager is the same class that provided by pptang in above mentioned question.
Actually I am newbie in android,If you ever crossover this kind of problem let me know the mistake that I have done . Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView sizes itself based on its child views if wrap_content and no explicit minimum height has been set.
In your child RecyclerView you have to consider change as follows

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/product_recycle_list"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

you are using horizontal recyclerView so set the

this will works if you want to know more about this problem visit https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772
it will help you.