# RecyclerView with different Cardview that hold other list in them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a `recyclerView` with two `cardView` one with `plain text` and the other with a list of data which is not specified. I have no problem creating two different view holder and set one single text data on first. The problem is how to load a list inside the 2nd `cardView`. Is it possible to create a `list view` adapter inside a `recyclerView` adapter ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement Custom `LayoutManager` for that. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32086918/4321808) answer for an example and explanation of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code so that we can better understand your issue. 
You can place a recycler view inside the second card view. And you can override `getItemViewType()` in adapter to handle the two card views.

Comment: The issue is not that. both the cardview show up exatly as wanted. But the problem is first recycler view is scrollable and the second recycler view inside the 2nd cardview is also havving scroll bar. Sometimes the first scrolls and evrything works nice. but when the second gets focus and scrolls nothing happens. I am my self a bit confused now