# RecyclerView in RecyclerView not scolling

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to create horizontal recycler inside another horizontal recycler but the problem is that the outer recycler is the only scrollable thing

I tried

```
daysRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
```

not working 
this is a test project : github.com/osama-raddad/RCTest

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011995/how-to-have-a-listview-recyclerview-inside-a-parent-recyclerview/32086918#32086918

Comment: no good my friend

Comment: please share the xml that you are using !

Comment: you can see a test project here https://github.com/osama-raddad/RCTest

Comment: how about having two recyclerView packed up in Root of NEstedScrollView?

Comment: how is that i am not getting your point