# Recycler View scrolling in both direction

Tags: android

RecyclerView with  vertical scrolling working fine. now i want that item of RecycelerView should be also scroll in horizontal direction in android. how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `LinearLayoutManager` to `Horizontal` orientation .. 
Try like this

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(
          new LinearLayoutManager(Activity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Hope this helps

EDIT

Try [this](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground)

There is [FixedGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/299515e0cfe4caea78eaf7ba12f7c9cf926b6063/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java) Which is scrollable in bothways.
And also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886447/android-nested-recyclerview)

Comment: i want vertical scrolling as well ad horizontal scrolling....the item of RecyclerView scroll in horizontal direction ...means one more list add which scroll in horizontal direction in item on RecyclerView..

Comment: Ok .. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886447/android-nested-recyclerview)

Comment: thanks Sanoop ..using this link my work has  done.. good answer and thanks for help!

Comment: It's wrong answer. @aj0822 wants both scrolling, not only horizontal

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ...
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**when you want horizontal**

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
```

**when you want vertical**

```
layoutManager.setOrientation(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
```

Comment: i want vertical scrolling as well ad horizontal scrolling....the item of RecyclerView scroll in horizontal direction ...means one more list add which scroll in horizontal direction in item on RecyclerView..

Comment: add it to a scroll view