# Why my main background wrap content instead of match parent?

Tags: android, layout

I have been doing a nested recyclerView lately, and thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content) I managed to solve the problem. But why my main background is wrap content to the custom layout instead of match parent?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFC18D"
android:id="@+id/fLayout">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llTextHolder">
        <TextView
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/tvCardHeader"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/takwimRecyclerViewList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas why is the happening?

Comment: Try to given weight to RecycleView.

Comment: @HareshChhelana how eh? im not very clear. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

wrapcontent means it will wrap the content according to its size i.e it will shrink or expand according.
matchparent will match the parent regardless of its size and will not look good.

Comment: i know the meaning of the wrap_content and match_parent. but why the "framelayout" (the orange color) follow the size of the content?

Comment: Sorry i did not got your question.But you can change to fillparent or match parent.

Comment: mmm. u see the framelayout, its already set to "match_parent"