# Horizontal RecycleView doesn't display its full content

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

I have a ListView and inside it I want horizontal RecyclerView with custom items. Problem is that somehow TextView under each image isn't displayed.

[image]

Main ListView item with RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/category_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Single item of RecyclerView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try getting reference to the textview which is not displayed. Then log the values of getX() and getY() method to find if they are positioned on the screen, and overlapped my some other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"

    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView 
       android:layout_weight="1" 

        android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: almost, I can see half of the text. A lilte bit of explanation would be great!

Comment: Try giving the weightSum for LinearLayout  3  ,  and for the ImageView 2, TextView 1.  This is like allocating the space , out of the total available space.   Also, set the width to 0dp   . this should Help u

Comment: Cool. Good luck Tomek

Answer (score 0):

you used 100dp `android:layout_height`but image and text are taller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:weight="70"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/horizontal_list_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:weight="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

In that case the image will take 70% of the size and the textview will be the other 30%.

Comment: I had to  add `dp` to 0, but still somehow this doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Try to make RecyclerView item android:layout_height to **match_parent** instead of **wrap_content**

Comment: then everything is gone. No  image no text.

Comment: In case you want know the main reason try to go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content and take code from Kaerdan answer (setting his layout manager to RecyclerView) and setting recyclerview height to wrap_content . http://gyazo.com/422570986cf450ea7a254f01f1eb2069

Comment: so much workaround for such simple thing... I should have used `TwoWayListView`.

Comment: I'm using HorizontalListView (https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) in my project