# How to make a bi-directional RecyclerView?

Tags: android, list, scroll, android-recyclerview, bidirectional

I need to be able to make a bi-directional `RecyclerView`. Basically, it would scroll vertically, but each row would be a horizontal list of tiles that could scroll. The initial scroll position would be at the top and left. The user could scroll down, and scroll to the right with each row.

Any ideas on how to do this? (e.g. with a custom `LayoutManager` or touch event interception).

Comment: Try nested recycler views. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C5I1DAviJ8 at some point in the presentation he speaks about what you want(or at least I think so)

Comment: `Basically, it would scroll vertically, but each row would be a horizontal list of tiles that could scroll.` **conflicts with** `scrollable views should not go in scrollable views` (which is **true**): That said, you could put a GridView in your RecyclerView's rows.

Comment: @DerGolem I know. There's ways to do it. Google engineers acknowledged that it's possible at some point for ListViews, but RecyclerViews are not ScrollViews and they do not measure themselves the same way as a ListView.

Comment: How would you `scroll horizontally` without a scrollable View? Which is **inside** your `vertically scrollable` View. If you want both directions of scrolls... No one can save you. You **must** use a Scrollable in a Scrollable (which is **terrible**).

Comment: If you understand the code you linked, you'll see that that is a Scrollable in a Scrollable. There's no way to get out of it. It's really a `conditio sine qua non`.

Comment: @DerGolem an example of how they work differently: if you put a RecyclerView in a dialog, the dialog will fill the max height of a dialog regardless of content. ListViews do not. 

That's why material-dialogs (one of my libraries) uses ListViews rather than RecyclerViews. https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs. RecyclerViews measure differently via their layout managers.

Comment: A ReciclerView is **obviously** not a ScrollView (**and who talked about ScrollViews?**). I am talking about **Scrollables** (which are **all those Views which can scroll**).

Comment: Then you're aware that you **can't have a scroll** (either horizontal or vertical) **without a Scrollable**.

Comment: @DerGolem yep. That's not the issue here. While Google advises people to not nest ScrollViews in ScrollViews, it's possible to do so with touch event interception. I'm looking for a solution with `RecyclerViews` and `LayoutManagers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using a custom view implementation.

At the root, I have a custom `ScrollView`; when `onMeasure` is called, the `ScrollView` tells its children how tall they should. In this case, they are half the height of the `ScrollView`. The width matches the height so they display as square tiles.

Each of the `ScrollView` children are `RecyclerView`'s with a horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`. Since the `ScrollView` tells each child how tall to be, there's no issues with measurement and they actually scroll very well in both directions (vertically and horizontally).

[image: sample of solution]

Comment: `Each of the ScrollView children are RecyclerView's` - but ScrollView can contains only one child.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov that one child is a `RecyclerView`.