# RecyclerView -GridLayout set WrapContent

Tags: android

I have create RecyclerView using **GridlayoutManager** but showing full screen(match_parent) how to RecyclerView  set as wrap_content?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Comment: hi second link check but i am using gridlayoutmanager .if LinearLayoutmanager use then (cell divider not working means 7 cell how to passed in linearlayoutmanager)