# Android - "wrap_content" doesn't wrap the content

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to make my Recycler view to not take all the screen space when there are just a few items on it using `wrap_content`, but that doesn't seem to work. What's the problem?

[image]
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/smoke_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:elevation="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use  **android:layout_weight="1"** in RecyclerView  not 0.8 and Linear layout 
**android:layout_width="wrap_content"** not fill_parent

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is that `RecyclerView` does not support `wrap_content` by default. You have to struggle a bit and provide it with a `LayoutManager` that can force your `RecyclerView` to wrap its contents.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content).

Answer (score 1):

You provided LinearLayout width to fill parent and weightSum to 1. Then set the layout_weight to 0.8. So, your total layout width size is 1 and you set layout_weight of recycleview to 0.8 so it takes the 80% of width.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

change height from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/smoke_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
```