# scrollview inside a fragment is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-linearlayout

i am new in app development.

i am using 3 tabs. in each fragment i want to display a list of cardview(7-8 cards).

my first fragment.xml

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/crt1"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:src="@drawable/c_3musketeers" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Three Musketeers"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rare | Air + Ground"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Three Musketeers"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/crt2"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:src="@drawable/c_archers" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Archers"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Common | Air + Ground"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

when i install this ap it is not scrolling at all.

my fragment.java file

```
public class TroopsFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ScrollView scrollview1 = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.troops,
            container, false);


    CardView cvt1;
    cvt1 = (CardView) scrollview1.findViewById(R.id.crt1);


    cvt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tushar kalsara",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return scrollview1;
}}
```

Comment: remove **android:orientation="vertical"**  from linearlayout below ScrollView.

Comment: after that how can i make my list vertical @amit vaghela

Comment: If you are using Constraint Layout, then, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453367/scrollview-inside-constraint-layout-does-not-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-the-parent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this property in ScrollView

`android:isScrollContainer="false"`

and Make `LinearLayout` to

`wrap_content`

Comment: Also add  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Answer (score 2):

Using a nested scrollview for fragment views does the trick for achieving scrollable views:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in ScrollView

> **android:isScrollContainer="false"**

and Make LinerLayout to

> wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

change scrollview's height to wrap content

and its children layouts to wrap content

then it will work

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:src="@drawable/c_3musketeers" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Three Musketeers"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Rare | Air + Ground"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Three Musketeers"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:src="@drawable/c_archers" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Archers"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Common | Air + Ground"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this might work. :)

Comment: please add details to your answer with code snip, else this will just like a comment

Answer (score 0):

You should never put a scrollable view inside another scrollable view. (in your example you have `cardviews` in `scrollview`).

However, if you insist on doing that anyway check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337403/making-recyclerview-fixed-height-and-scrollable). You can set fixed heights on `cardviews`

It can be done also for `listviews`. See [this blog](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/) if you need it