# RecyclerView inside a LinearLayout along with several other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView inside my LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/book_detail_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.BookDetailActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:id="@+id/book_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/book_default"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/book_authors"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:max="5"
                android:id="@+id/book_rating"
                android:stepSize="0.5"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:progressTint="#FFA500"
                android:secondaryProgressTint="#D1D6D8"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/book_rating_text"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/book_reviews_text"
            android:textColor="@color/redColor"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:id="@+id/book_description"
            android:onClick="toggleText"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:id="@+id/book_description_below_line"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#EEEEEE"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_translucent_black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="People near you who are willing to lend this book"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lender_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that when I inflate this recyclerView, the complete activity is not scrolling (Only the part of recycler view does). Moreover I have specify height of recyclerView otherwise I am not able to see it.

So my two problems are:

1. **How to give this RecyclerView hight dynamically (`layout_height: wrap_content` isn't working)**
2. **How to scroll the entire activity (and not just the recyclerView part) when content is more.**

***P.S I am new to Android, though I have implemented recyclerView earlier but in those cases there was only one element (one recyclerView inside a parent LinearLayout)***

Comment: @b1izzard I had also found this post but can you tell me why wrap_content isn't working here, Isn't there any other way than setting height from java file?

Comment: Which LayoutManager are u using?

Comment: @Abhay LinearLayoutManager

Comment: @Abhishek Could you check using `fillViewPort` option for `Scrollview` and check? What version of support library you are using?

Comment: @b1izzard yes already checked with fillViewPort (no help).
version is 23.1.1

Comment: You can use customized listview instead,it will fix your problem. Check my answer

Comment: @Abhishek Use the latest version of support library(`23.3.0`) and check. The issue with wrap content is fixed in `23.2`, read the recyclerview [changelog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html).

Comment: @Abhishek: check this questions's accepted answer,hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337403/making-recyclerview-fixed-height-and-scrollable

Answer (score 0):

ExpandableHeightListView.java

```
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Context;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {

        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Add this customized java file and use it in xml.
and in your MainActivity do like this:

```
   ExpandableHeightListView  listview= (ExpandableHeightListView) findViewById(R.id.comment_listview);
```

and set adapter and set one property

```
listview.setAdapter("Your Adapter");
listview.setExpanded(true);
```

Comment: I am using recyclerView not listView

Comment: Yes i know ,You are using LinearLayoutManager that's why i suggested you to use this customized listview class.It will help you to solve your problem