# RecyclerView is not taking wrap_content height, it becomes scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Details:**

**Dependency: (latest)**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_gray">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginTwenty"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginTwenty"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contactLoadingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/marginThirty">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/waitText"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contactsLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mobileView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mobile" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMobileNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/mobileNumber"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mobileRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoMobileData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddMobile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/emailView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtEmailNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/email"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/emailRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoEmailData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/facebookView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/facebookHint"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/facebookRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoFacebookData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddFacebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linkedInView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_linkedi" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLinkedIn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/linkedInHint"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/linkedInRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoLinkedInData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddLinkedIn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/twitterView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_twitter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTwitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/twitterHint"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/twitterRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoTwitterData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddTwitter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtubeView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/youtubeHint"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoYoutubeData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddYoutube"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gitHubView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginTwenty"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen"
            android:background="@drawable/curved_background_white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/marginTen">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/marginTwenty"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/dummyContent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_github" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:text="@string/gitHubHint"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/githubRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNoGitHubData"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/marginTen"
                android:text="@string/no_contact_found"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnAddGithub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/noInternetLayoutContact"
        layout="@layout/no_internet_layout"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**JAVA Code:**

```
youtubeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
youtubeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
youtubeRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
youtubeRecyclerView.setAdapter(attributeAdapter);
youtubeRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

### **Note:**

- i have 6 recycler views in single activity and out of those 6 any one of the recycler view becomes scrollable and rest works fine (wrap_content) based on screen size.
- My Parent View is ScrollView.

I have done enough research on internet and stackoverflow, couldn't find the solution, So asked question here. Please don't mark as duplicate.

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"`   are properties of imageView

Comment: Please post whole your xml file. It is hard to understand what would you like to get ;)

Comment: My recyclerview was without those properties, I tried that just experiment it didn't worked out.

Comment: @muminers, added whole XML file code.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32390370/5148289) solution

Comment: Why do you use a RecyclerView if you don't want it to scroll? It kind of defies its purpose. You could go on with static layouts instead. And having one scroll/recycler view inside another is usually a bad idea.

Comment: my list will have 5-6 items maximum, so i want user to see whole recyclerview instead of scrollview. and when the list decreases to 1 or 2 or 3 items it should automatically decrease.

Comment: How ever i can give a fixed height to my recyclerview and make it scrollable if the items get increased 5 (which might not happen) but if the list count is 2 or 3 recyclerview will have empty white space which will look bad

Comment: @KhanStan99 what you can do is use `NonScrollListView` instead `recyclerview`. they will automatically resized according to items in the list

Comment: Yes i can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by putting my recyclerview in a nestedscrollview and kept 'android:nestedScrollingEnabled' disabled/false.

Comment: Placing a recycler view inside a nested scroll view disables view recycling and therefore defeats the purpose of using a recyclerview. If you have a large list of data this will all be drawn at create time and would cause the main thread to lag.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping **`RecyclerView`** using fixed height parent

> You can go for **a fixed height** or **`wrap_content`** for `LinearLayout` parent

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRecyclerContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTen">

             <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/facebookRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
          </LinearLayout>
```

In your java file :

```
facebookRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: In this case what if the size is small? like 2 items? in that case it will have empty white space, which will make the UI look bad

Comment: RecyclerView will get scrolled in this fixed area you are wrapping

Comment: That was my question bro. I gave recyclerview wrapcontent height, but it is becoming scrollable when the list length increases 3 which i dont want. I want to set height of my all 6 recyclerview scrollable even if the list size increases 3.

Comment: Please check my question. i already gave youtubeRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use `RecycylerView` inside `scrollView` as result it won't support recycling if views.

Better use one vertical parent `RecyclerView` and based on view type add your child `RecyclerView` to parent.