# How to set minimum vertical scroll range for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Is it possible to make `RecyclerView` have a minimum vertical scroll distance?

(e.g. just render nothing/transparency if not enough items)

Comment: Please refer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337403/making-recyclerview-fixed-height-and-scrollable

Comment: @faran.javed Although related, I do not believe that post to be an answer to this one.