# Nested/Child RecyclerView inside parent RecyclerView with custom LinearLayoutManager not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I tried following [this SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28303955/4031815) of how to use the custom `LinearLayoutManager`, but my nested `RecyclerView`isn't displaying at all.

## Parent RecyclerView in Activity:

```
        RecyclerView detailsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.category_dish_dialog_recycler_view);
        detailsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CategoryActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        detailsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DishDetailsAdapter detailsAdapter = new DishDetailsAdapter(dish.getDishOptions(), CategoryActivity.this);
        detailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);

        detailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

## Adapter for Parent Recycler View:

Notice that child/nested RecyclerView is inside `OptionsViewHolder`:

```
public class DishDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DishOption> options;
    private Context context;
    private SharedData sharedData = SharedData.getInstance();


    public DishDetailsAdapter(List<DishOption> detailsList, Context parentContext) {
        options = detailsList;
        context = parentContext;
        sharedData.setMainFont(context);
        sharedData.setSecondaryFont(context);
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_dish_dialog_option, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = new OptionsViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DishOption dishOption = options.get(position);

        OptionsViewHolder vh = (OptionsViewHolder) holder;

        vh.optionName.setText(dishOption.getTitle());
        vh.optionName.setTypeface(sharedData.getSecondaryFont());

        List<DishOptionItem> dishOptionItems = dishOption.getItems();


        ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(dishOptionItems, context);

        //NOTICE CHILD/NESTED RECYCLER VIEW HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        vh.nestedRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new NestedLinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        vh.nestedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return options.size();
    }


    /**
     * View holders for dish options Options
     */
    public class OptionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView optionName;
        private RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView;

        public OptionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            optionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_dialog_option_title);
            nestedRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_nested_recycler_view);

        }
    }
}
```

## Child/Nested RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DishOptionItem> items;
    private Context context;
    private SharedData sharedData = SharedData.getInstance();

    public ItemsAdapter(List<DishOptionItem> itemsList, Context parentParentContext) {
        items = itemsList;
        context = parentParentContext;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_dish_dialog_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DishOptionItem item = items.get(position);

        ItemViewHolder iVH = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

        iVH.itemName.setText(item.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    /**
     * View holders for dish options Items
     */
    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView itemName;
        private TextView itemPrice;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_dialog_item_name);
            //itemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_dialog_item_price);
        }
    }

}
```

## Finally the custom LinearLayoutManager:

```
public class NestedLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {


    public NestedLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }

        // If child view is more than screen size, there is no need to make it wrap content. We can use original onMeasure() so we can scroll view.
        if (height < heightSize && width < widthSize) {

            switch (widthMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    width = widthSize;
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            switch (heightMode) {
                case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    height = heightSize;
                case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        }
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {

        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);

        // For adding Item Decor Insets to view
        super.measureChildWithMargins(view, 0, 0);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + getDecoratedLeft(view) + getDecoratedRight(view), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + getPaddingBottom() + getDecoratedBottom(view) , p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

            // Get decorated measurements
            measuredDimension[0] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(view) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(view) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

If someone thinks they need to see the xml layout files I can post them here. Please help I don't know what else to try.