# CardView wrap its content dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following card in layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- [a RecyclerView as list with LinearLayout as header] -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/total_label"
            android:layout_below="@id/label"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

        <!-- [a LinearLayout with 2 TextViews] -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/total_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

What I try to achieve is to click on label `TextView` and hide the other content from the card (let visible only its label component). Again, by clicking further the label expand the hidden content. I can do that if I set explicitly the height of the card i.e. `400dp`, BUT that way if the containing `RecyclerView` used as list have not many items (which all are the same height and fixed) there is much empty space. How can the card wrap its content? (When I use `wrap_content` in `layout_height` of the card only the label is visible).

This is the click handler for the card:

```
card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Resources r = getResources();

                if (toggle) {
                    tableContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    totalLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    float pxTopMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_list_margin_top), r.getDisplayMetrics());

                    params.topMargin = (int) pxTopMargin;

                    card.setLayoutParams(params);
                    card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    tableContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    totalLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    float pxHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 400, r.getDisplayMetrics());

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) pxHeight);

                    float pxTopMargin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.card_list_margin_top), r.getDisplayMetrics());

                    params.topMargin = (int) pxTopMargin;
                    params.bottomMargin = (int) pxTopMargin;

                    card.setLayoutParams(params);
                    card.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
```

### SOLUTION

ok the problem actually was to create list using `RecyclerView` that has the property:

A specific number of rows to be visible (i.e. 15) and if lower then wrap its content

I found from [other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content) (comment by **se.solovyev**) a custom linear layout and edited a little. The result was satisfying (although I don't actually know if did something really bad in there, but works).

```
package com.trafficbroker.trafficbroker.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * {@link android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager} which wraps its content. Note that this class will always
 * wrap the content regardless of {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView} layout parameters.
 * <p/>
 * Now it's impossible to run add/remove animations with child views which have arbitrary dimensions (height for
 * VERTICAL orientation and width for HORIZONTAL). However if child views have fixed dimensions
 * {@link #setChildSize(int)} method might be used to let the layout manager know how big they are going to be.
 * If animations are not used at all then a normal measuring procedure will run and child views will be measured during
 * the measure pass.
 */
public class WrappingLinearLayoutManager extends    android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager {

private static boolean canMakeInsetsDirty = true;
private static Field insetsDirtyField = null;

private static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 1;
private static final int DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE = 100;

private final int[] childDimensions = new int[2];
private final RecyclerView view;

private int childSize = DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE;
private boolean hasChildSize;
private int overScrollMode = ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS;
private final Rect tmpRect = new Rect();

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrappingLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrappingLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrappingLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view) {
    super(view.getContext());
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public WrappingLinearLayoutManager(RecyclerView view, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(view.getContext(), orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.view = view;
    this.overScrollMode = ViewCompat.getOverScrollMode(view);
}

public void setOverScrollMode(int overScrollMode) {
    if (overScrollMode < ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS || overScrollMode > ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown overscroll mode: " + overScrollMode);
    if (this.view == null) throw new IllegalStateException("view == null");
    this.overScrollMode = overScrollMode;
    ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, overScrollMode);
}

public static int makeUnspecifiedSpec() {
    return View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);

    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    final boolean hasWidthSize = widthMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;
    final boolean hasHeightSize = heightMode != View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

    final boolean exactWidth = widthMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    final boolean exactHeight = heightMode == View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

    final int unspecified = makeUnspecifiedSpec();

    if (exactWidth && exactHeight) {
        // in case of exact calculations for both dimensions let's use default "onMeasure" implementation
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        return;
    }

    final boolean vertical = getOrientation() == VERTICAL;

    initChildDimensions(widthSize, heightSize, vertical);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // it's possible to get scrap views in recycler which are bound to old (invalid) adapter entities. This
    // happens because their invalidation happens after "onMeasure" method. As a workaround let's clear the
    // recycler now (it should not cause any performance issues while scrolling as "onMeasure" is never
    // called whiles scrolling)
    recycler.clear();

    final int stateItemCount = state.getItemCount();
    final int adapterItemCount = (getItemCount() < 15 ? getItemCount() : 15);//getItemCount();   // MAX VISIBLE ROWS
    // adapter always contains actual data while state might contain old data (f.e. data before the animation is
    // done). As we want to measure the view with actual data we must use data from the adapter and not from  the
    // state
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterItemCount; i++) {
        if (vertical) {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, widthSize, unspecified, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            height += childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            if (i == 0) {
                width = childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            }
            if (hasHeightSize && height >= heightSize) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (!hasChildSize) {
                if (i < stateItemCount) {
                    // we should not exceed state count, otherwise we'll get IndexOutOfBoundsException. For such items
                    // we will use previously calculated dimensions
                    measureChild(recycler, i, unspecified, heightSize, childDimensions);
                } else {
                    logMeasureWarning(i);
                }
            }
            width += childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH];
            if (i == 0) {
                height = childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT];
            }
            if (hasWidthSize && width >= widthSize) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (exactWidth) {
        width = widthSize;
    } else {
        width += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        if (hasWidthSize) {
            width = Math.min(width, widthSize);
        }
    }

    if (exactHeight) {
        height = heightSize;
    } else {
        height += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        if (hasHeightSize) {
            height = Math.min(height, heightSize);
        }
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (view != null && overScrollMode == ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS) {
        final boolean fit = (vertical && (!hasHeightSize || height < heightSize))
                || (!vertical && (!hasWidthSize || width < widthSize));

        ViewCompat.setOverScrollMode(view, fit ? ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER : ViewCompat.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void logMeasureWarning(int child) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "Can't measure child #" + child + ", previously used dimensions will be reused." +
                "To remove this message either use #setChildSize() method or don't run RecyclerView animations");
    }
}

private void initChildDimensions(int width, int height, boolean vertical) {
    if (childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] != 0 || childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] != 0) {
        // already initialized, skipping
        return;
    }
    if (vertical) {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = width;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = childSize;
    } else {
        childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = childSize;
        childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = height;
    }
}

@Override
public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    // might be called before the constructor of this class is called
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    if (childDimensions != null) {
        if (getOrientation() != orientation) {
            childDimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = 0;
            childDimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = 0;
        }
    }
    super.setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void clearChildSize() {
    hasChildSize = false;
    setChildSize(DEFAULT_CHILD_SIZE);
}

public void setChildSize(int childSize) {
    hasChildSize = true;
    if (this.childSize != childSize) {
        this.childSize = childSize;
        requestLayout();
    }
}

private void measureChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSize, int heightSize, int[] dimensions) {
    final View child;
    try {
        child = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "LinearLayoutManager doesn't work well with animations. Consider switching them off", e);
        }
        return;
    }

    final RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

    final int hPadding = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    final int vPadding = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    final int hMargin = p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    final int vMargin = p.topMargin + p.bottomMargin;

    // we must make insets dirty in order calculateItemDecorationsForChild to work
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    // this method should be called before any getXxxDecorationXxx() methods
    calculateItemDecorationsForChild(child, tmpRect);

    final int hDecoration = getRightDecorationWidth(child) + getLeftDecorationWidth(child);
    final int vDecoration = getTopDecorationHeight(child) + getBottomDecorationHeight(child);

    final int childWidthSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthSize, hPadding + hMargin + hDecoration, p.width, canScrollHorizontally());
    final int childHeightSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightSize, vPadding + vMargin + vDecoration, p.height, canScrollVertically());

    child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);

    dimensions[CHILD_WIDTH] = getDecoratedMeasuredWidth(child) + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
    dimensions[CHILD_HEIGHT] = getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(child) + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;

    // as view is recycled let's not keep old measured values
    makeInsetsDirty(p);
    recycler.recycleView(child);
}

private static void makeInsetsDirty(RecyclerView.LayoutParams p) {
    if (!canMakeInsetsDirty) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (insetsDirtyField == null) {
            insetsDirtyField = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.class.getDeclaredField("mInsetsDirty");
            insetsDirtyField.setAccessible(true);
        }
        insetsDirtyField.set(p, true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        onMakeInsertDirtyFailed();
    }
}

private static void onMakeInsertDirtyFailed() {
    canMakeInsetsDirty = false;
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.w("LinearLayoutManager", "Can't make LayoutParams insets dirty, decorations measurements might be incorrect");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an example as close to yours as I could, but the key seems to be

```
card.requestLayout();
```

Here's what I had for the CardView

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <!-- [a RecyclerView as list with LinearLayout as header] -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/table_container"

            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/label"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

        <!-- [a LinearLayout with 2 TextViews] -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/total_label"
            android:id="@+id/total_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/table" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here's what I had for the listener

```
card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toggle) {
                tableContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                totalLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tableContainer.getLayoutParams();
                //params.height = 1500;
                //tableContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            } else {
                tableContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                totalLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =   tableContainer.getLayoutParams();
                //params.height = 1500;
                //tableContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            toggle = !toggle;
            card.requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Here's an example of one of the layouts that go into the include tags.

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/total_labeltv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="total label"
    android:background="#C0c0c0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a try to the example and your time. This seems a nice refactoring to force the layout being drawn BUT do you have an idea how to replace the `params.height = 1500` with `WRAP_CONTENT` and still work (actually that was the main question how to make the `WRAP_CONTENT` work because in the example the list is not visible. Note: the list populated from web service.)?

Comment: I added an example of one of the layouts I used for the include tags. The height there is "wrap_content" initially. Those hard-coded height changes (params.height = 1500) were programmatic and only in the onClick method to demonstrate that the CardView would update in size when its content changed size. I'll remove those lines for clarity.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. I have to explicitly give height value in DP both in layout declaration and in click hander using LayoutParams. Otherwise, only the card label is visible although clicking on it will do no expanding/wrapping to its contents.