# NullPointerException in dissapearence animation of RecyclerView from support v.23.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

In new RecyclerView we can use `wrap_content` for height (or for width). So Google fixed bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74772

But not all is well in the end.

I try to use animation of dissapearence when remove item from RecyclerView.
So i use method of Adapter - notifyItemRemoved(int) with any argument and RecyclerView cause NullPointerException.


Xml code:

```
...
    <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="always"/>
    ...
```

Logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.animateDisappearance(SimpleItemAnimator.java:78)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.animateDisappearance(RecyclerView.java:3246)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$700(RecyclerView.java:147)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$4.processDisappeared(RecyclerView.java:422)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ViewInfoStore.process(ViewInfoStore.java:231)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3(RecyclerView.java:3086)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2914)
     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3277)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14015)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Maybe there are temp workarounds of these problem?


**EDIT**

I tried to reproduce in new project. So no exceptions was thrown. Maybe in my project there are others dependencies which call this problem.

Comment: I've got the exact same issue. I guess it is a bug in the support library. I don't even animate my entries in any other way than default animation within notify... methods

Comment: Can you create a bug report with a sample app that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I have this exception too. It happens when I try to add items to `RecyclerView` and these items must go beyond the visible portion of the `RecyclerView`. It only happens on `RecyclerView`s that have `GridLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same error as the one raised in the question and in fact have raised a bug with Google for this. I did find, after delving into the framework code, that I could resolve the issue by changing the setting of HasFixedSize from FALSE to TRUE i.e. "rv.setHasFixedSize(true)". This is basically telling the RecyclerView that changes to its contents will not change the RecyclerView size thus avoiding a full layout. I had originally set this FALSE due to a mis-interpretation of its meaning. This change removes the fault for me and is a reproducible solution.

Answer (score 5):

Google has made some statement about the usage of the RecyclerView with the version 23.2 of the Support Library.

Link to the blog post (check the RecyclerView section): http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> Due to this change, make sure to double check the layout parameters of your item views: previously ignored layout parameters (such as MATCH_PARENT in the scroll direction) will now be fully respected.

I would suggest you to try to change your RecyclerView's `layout_height` param to `match_parent`. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Yep, with match_parent RecyclerView doesn't cause exception. But i need in wrap_content.

Comment: Yeah, I've read some discussions about it, I think you should fill a bug at http://b.android.com, as yigit suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same exception. It occurs when I add a view to the `RecyclerView` and that view is completely beyond the boundaries of the `RecyclerView` (user would have to scroll to see that newly added view).

However, I've noticed that this exception only occurs when width or height of the `RecyclerView` is `wrap_content` or `0dp` with weight set to 1 inside a `LinearLayout`... If I set the width and height to any other value except those two, i.e. `140dp`, `match_parent`, then everything works fine.

So, I've tried to trick the buggy framework and find a solution to set the width of my `RecyclerView` to be as big as there are space left inside my `LinearLayout` that contains the `RecyclerView` (width:0dp, weight:1 combination), so I wrapped the `RecyclerView` inside another `LinearLayout` with weight set to 1, and set my `RecyclerView`'s width to `match_parent`, so it gets as wide as parent `LinearLayout` can get, and the parent `LinearLayout` fills the free space in another parent `LinearLayout`. And voila, it works perfectly!

I know, it sounds ridiculous, but that's the way I worked it out...

Here's the source code if anybody needs to get the idea of how to workaround this bug...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/pic_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:background="#BBB"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pic_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pic_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `RecyclerView` now is as wide as there are free space in the parent `LinearLayout`, which also contains one button to the right of the `RecyclerView`, and no crashes occurs.

If anybody finds out the real cause of such an exception or a better way to fix it, please share...