# Nested recylerview lag while first few scrolls and then scrolls smoothly?

Tags: android, performance, adapter, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using nested RecyclerView. Means inside a vertical RecyclerView I have multiple horizontal recycler view

I am attaching adapter to horizontal recylerviews inside onBindViewHolder method of parent RecyclerView as follows.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case TYPE_PRODUCT:
            ((ListHolderProduct) holder).itemTitle.setText(browseCategoryHomePageItems.get(position).displayName.toUpperCase());
            ((ListHolderProduct) holder).recyclerView.setAdapter(new CarouselProductsRecyclerAdapter(context
                    , browseCategoryHomePageItems.get(position).products
                    , R.layout.activity_categoryhome_products_grid_item
                    , nestedRecyclerItemClickedListener
                    , position));
            break;
        case TYPE_DEAL:
            ((ListHolderDeal) holder).itemTitle.setText(browseCategoryHomePageItems.get(position).displayName.toUpperCase());
            ((ListHolderDeal) holder).recyclerView.setAdapter(new CarouselDealsRecyclerAdapter(context
                    , browseCategoryHomePageItems.get(position).dealItems
                    , R.layout.activity_categoryhome_deals_grid_item
                    , nestedRecyclerItemClickedListener
                    , position));
            break;
            //few more types like this
    }
}
```

Now whenever I scroll page it is lagging a bit since I am attaching adapter to horizontal RecyclerView on OnBindViewHolder

**And there can be N Number of TYPE_PRODUCT or any type of horizontal lists.
Means there can be more that one horizontal lists of same type.**

Any idea how can I optimize this thing and improve the scroll speed.

It is lagging since setAdapter is called every time for list previously.

**Update on this I am extending LinearLayoutManager and in that I am setting extraLayout space which has fixed my issue but I don't know this is right way or not I am setting extra space as below.**

```
 layoutManager.setExtraLayoutSpace(2 * this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
```

and follwoing is custom layout manager class

```
public class PreCachingLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
private static final int DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE = 600;
private int extraLayoutSpace = -1;
private Context context;

public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context, int extraLayoutSpace) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
}

public PreCachingLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.context = context;
}

public void setExtraLayoutSpace(int extraLayoutSpace) {
    this.extraLayoutSpace = extraLayoutSpace;
}

@Override
protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (extraLayoutSpace > 0) {
        return extraLayoutSpace;
    }
    return DEFAULT_EXTRA_LAYOUT_SPACE;
}
```

}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content

Comment: no my question different I am facing lag while scroll

Comment: Thanks for solution with getExtraLayoutSpace! I have not found better solution, but i add one improvement - i return extra space only first time, and return zero in other cases.

Answer (score 5):

Do not create horizontal `adapter` every time in `onBindViewHolder`, instead in each `ViewHolder` class(ListHolderDeal, ListHolderProduct) create appropriate adapter. Then in `onBindViewHolder` of vertical `Recyclerview`  just replace the data of that adapter and if the horizontal `RecyclerView` does not have an adapter set it with the viewholder adapter. If it does, replace the data set of that `adapter` and call `notifyDataSetChange`. With this approach, you can use adapter pool implicitly so the GC may less bother you.

I hope it helps.

Comment: okay so do you want me to have adapter variable in viewholder itself and then just update in onBindViewHolder right?

Comment: yes, because we do not want to create unnecessary objects.

Comment: Hi but i will have to initialize adapter in onBindViewHolder  because the arraylist will be empty if I try to initialize it inside ViewHolder

Comment: this is also not working it is lagging on first two scrolls then working fine

Comment: @apk How did you initialized the adapter in the ViewHolder? Did it raised null pointer exception?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with scrolling, because of loading images while scrolling. So you need to use `Picasso` library for loading your images,  and to make `pause_tag` if you are using onScrollListener.

In your `onBindViewHolder`
                  Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(foodData.getRecipe_resize_image_url())
                        .resize(width, height)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_image)
                        .tag("resume_tag")
                        .into(mainViewHolder.food_picture);

In your `onScrollListener`

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    final Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        picasso.resumeTag("resume_tag");
    } else {
        picasso.pauseTag("resume_tag");
    }

}
```

Comment: How to handle this on glide.

Answer (score 2):

Create the Adapter at your ViewHolder creation, not binding. Also, be aware that sometimes, initial scroll lag happens due to the build variant you are testing on. Release APKs have better performance since the entire debugging tools and profilers activated on a Debug Build are not activated anymore. Most of my performance issues are solved on the release build.

Comment: huge +1 for the debug build variant

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have overrided `getItemViewType(int position)` method, if not please override this method and say how many type of views your recyclerview is going to handle, from the above code there are two types of view one for `TYPE_PRODUCT` and other for `TYPE_DEAL`.

This particular method if overriden and returns the type count correctly, it prevents unwanted layout inflation for the already available typed view(in recycler cache) which increases the performance drastically.

For example of implementing multiple typed recyclerview, [please refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).

Reference : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29

Hope this helps!!! Please let me know if you have any issues with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` uses view pool to prevent recreation of views which improve performance but when we use `RecyclerView` inside `RecyclerView` the inner `RecyclerView` has its own view pool so every time outer `RecyclerView` scrolls each view of the inner `RecyclerView` inflated  because it has a separate view pool.

So to use same view we need to add this code in outer `RecyclerView` adapter:

```
public OuterRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Item> items) {
    //Constructor stuff
    viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Create viewHolder etc
    holder.innerRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);

}
```

I found this info from this helpful [article](https://medium.com/@mgn524/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are focusing on the recycling part of the `RecyclerView`. If you look carefully, the problem is not about the recycling process at all. In order to have smooth behavior on the first scroll, you should preload the items when the outer adapter created. This can be done by extending `LinearLayoutManager` and overriding `calculateExtraLayoutSpace()` method.

```kotlin
// Utility to convert DP to PX
val Int.dp: Float get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()

// Assign LayoutManager to RecyclerView
recyclerView.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this) {
   override fun calculateExtraLayoutSpace(
      state: RecyclerView.State,
      extraLayoutSpace: IntArray
   ) {
      extraLayoutSpace[0] = 500.dp // Extra space for the top/left items
      extraLayoutSpace[1] = 500.dp // Extra space for the bottom/right items
   }
}
```

The extra space needed is depend on the size of your items. Choose wisely as this will cause `RecyclerView` to add extra items in the `ViewPool`. If the `LayoutManager` space is greater then your overall layout size, the items will not get recycled at all (because all items are visible by `LayoutManager`).