# How to fill RecyclerView with Single Item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, layout-manager

I had an app perfectly working with support library version 23.1.1, where a RecyclerView shows a Loading View during data fetch using a LinearLayoutManager and a RecyclerViewerAdapter.

------------------ **Chapter One - Everything Works** ----------------

*Showing Indicator in the middle. The Layout covers the whole view.*

[image]

*Gradle File Shows it is using 23.1.1 version of Support Libraries.*

[image: gradle 1]

*If you look at line 21, I get the height of parent view from Layout Manager and set it to the loading view.*

[image: Code]

------------------ **Chapter Two - Everything goes South** ----------------

*I updated the Support Library*

[image]

*Nothing shows up*

[image]

It turned out the parent.getMeasuredHeight() returns 0.

------------------ **Chapter Three - Some Hints** ----------------

From one of the answer from a [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content), I thought WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH PARENT will work instead of parent.getMeasuredHeight(). But, it did not help either.

*Result of WRAP_CONTENT*

[image]

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/cocoBavan/RecyclerViewPractice/tree/master)

Comment: Just put your `Recycleview` in some `Framelayout` add one imageview or something(your progress bar) in that. Make that view visible during the loading and make it invisible or gone when you need to fill data in `RecycleView`. **Why to complicate things by filling `RecylceView` with a single item you already have complications when you are using `RecycleView` as a newbie**

Comment: Here is the thread about setting `RecyclerView` height to wrap content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Comment: I agree with Janki. But, It will be a huge change in the code base which someone else wrote and claimed it completed. Anyway I have written a method which traces a view, with height greater than zero, up from the view group we have and use that height to set the height of our layout. It seems to work for now.